# Where can I find statistics about papers (length, writers, etc.)

Tags: publications, mathematics, reference-request, statistics

Different fields have different writing culture. Some fields prefer single author papers, and others prefer group efforts. Some fields prefer a short paper with a survey of a new results, and others prefer longer and more technical papers.

Specifically I'm interested in mathematics (and its subfields, if such breakdown exists). Is there any way to obtain some sort of statistics as to how many papers were published, how long they are, and how many writers were involved? Some statistical analysis and trend-changes would also be very interesting to me.

Do these statistics exist for other fields? I'd be interested in also knowing how different is the publishing culture in mathematics compared to other fields (STEM, social and humanities).

Comment: If this question is inappropriate, I apologize in advance. I was also a bit uncertain regarding the tags.

Comment: Related: in the past @PiotrMigdal has been actively interested in similar data analysis projects; see for instance https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2363/arxiv-vs-mathoverflow-popularity-of-disciplines, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38969/getting-a-dump-of-arxiv-metadata, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2139/an-interactive-graph-of-mathoverflow-tags.

Comment: For math, see the links in this answer for papers about this: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/41279/19607

Answer (score 4):

Scopus can provide you with a statistical analysis of publications that it has recorded that match a query. It's behind a paywall I think, but your organization might have a login.

Using it is pretty straightforward;

[image: Search]

[image: Advanced search]

If you want more information on the query format;

[image]

Then;

[image]

It can give you results over time or various filters etc.