# What kind of PhD proposals should I read?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, changing-fields

I am finishing up my master's in mathematical finance and am hoping to pursue a PhD in stochastic analysis.

I was given a sample PhD proposal from an education office that helps people apply for universities in the UK and some other countries (some of those countries [require specifically a PhD proposal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42377/what-is-common-in-most-phd-application-procedures-in-the-uk) so you can tell that the US is [not one of them](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42308/what-is-the-typical-phd-application-procedure-in-the-us)). I was told I should look at PhD proposals outside of my field and thus was given something in Chemistry.

Relevant links at this point:

1. No. 5 here: [With a background in mathematical finance and desire to apply for a mathematics PhD in another field, do I need a second master's?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/with-a-background-in-mathematical-finance-and-desire-to-apply-for-a-mathematics)
2. [How do mathematicians conduct research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/34038/22511)

As [mathematicians do not really collect data or conduct experiments for their research](http://36.media.tumblr.com/b7c651eba14e9a34af8a5eeab58c040f/tumblr_mkwkc5ThT91qaityko1_1280.jpg), I think I should countersuggest something in theoretical physics, theoretical computer science or something of the sort. Do you think that's okay? What would you suggest?

Comment: The education office's advice seems bizarre to me. If you want to write a proposal in mathematics, read mathematics proposals.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. Any suggestions of what to say without offending them?

Comment: Ask them the purpose of not providing a mathematics proposal. A hard science looking at a similar science might get tunnel vision, but I doubt a mathematics PhD would face the same problem seeing as they're less experimental method than other fields.

Comment: @Compass EXACTLY. However, I think theoretical physics and theoretical computer science is also not so experimental?

Comment: @Jack for sure. The first result for a `phd proposal theoretical` yields: http://www.ifsc.usp.br/~hoyos/Thesis_Alet.pdf They all seem to be at most a few pages long, and it probably wouldn't hurt just skimming a bunch of these before you have a good idea of what you need to do.

Comment: @Compass Cool. Thanks. What search engine are you using? It doesn't show on google's first page (I did find it in second though)

Comment: @Jack I forgot to add "physics" to the comment on retrospect.

Comment: @Compass You wanna make your comment an answer so I can give you the bounty?

Comment: @Jack I guess, but maybe someone will have a better answer soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask them the purpose of not providing a mathematics proposal. A hard science looking at a similar science might get tunnel vision, but I doubt a mathematics PhD would face the same problem seeing as they're less experimental method than other fields.

PhD proposals, unlike theses, also seem to be much more readily accessible online. A quick search for `theoretical physics phd proposal` on Google, even without Scholar, yields a decent amount of samples that provide a significant amount of differing examples in sufficiently different subjects from math that the content can be differentiated from the style.